# imageBitmap.width not equal Modifier.onSizeChanged { it.width }

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

`density.run { imageBitmap.width.toDp() }` not equal `Modifier.onSizeChanged { density.run { boxSize = it.width.toDp() }}`

I trying to made image cropper:

```
@Composable
fun ImageCropDialog(uri: Uri, onDismiss: (result: Resource<Bitmap>?) -> Unit) {

    Dialog(
        onDismissRequest = { onDismiss(null) },
        properties = DialogProperties(
            dismissOnClickOutside = false
        )
    ) {
        val context = LocalContext.current
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val imageBitmap = remember(uri) {
            val bitmap = uri.getBitmap(context)
            if (bitmap == null) onDismiss(Resource.Error("bitmap is null"))
            bitmap!!
        }
        val imageSize = remember(uri) {
            density.run { DpSize(imageBitmap.width.toDp(), imageBitmap.height.toDp()) }
        }

        var boxSize by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }

        var scale by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(1.1f) }
        var rotation by remember { mutableFloatStateOf(0f) }
        var offset by remember { mutableStateOf(Offset.Zero) }

        val state = rememberTransformableState { zoomChange, offsetChange, rotationChange ->
            scale = if (max(imageSize.height, imageSize.width) * scale * zoomChange > boxSize) scale * zoomChange else scale
    //            rotation += rotationChange
    //            offset += offsetChange
        }
        Box {
            AsyncImage(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .graphicsLayer(
                        scaleX = scale,
                        scaleY = scale,
                        rotationZ = rotation,
                        translationX = offset.x,
                        translationY = offset.y
                    )
                    .transformable(state = state)
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                model = uri,
                contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.image),
                contentScale = ContentScale.Fit
            )
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .background(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = .5f), RoundedCornerShape(16.dp))
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .aspectRatio(1f)
                    .padding(30.dp)
                    .align(Alignment.Center)
                    .onSizeChanged {
                        density.run { boxSize = it.width.toDp() }
                    }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

but when I try to limit the minimum image size within the gray square, the border is actually much smaller.
how to make a minimum size constraint equal to the size of the square?

what should be the minimum image size:

[image: what should be the minimum image size:]

real minimum image size:

[image: real minimum image size:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all the problems were due to the padding modifier on the box. If you remove it, then everything will fit together